# is this counted as a damaged passport? (Indian Passport)

Tags: visas, air-travel, passports, visa-refusals

I have mostly kept my passport in bag and i am not sure how it exactly happened or what, but I notice something on just 1 page, would that be counted as a damaged passport?
My detail page and threading and cover, everything else is fine. Just wondering about this page, all other pages are good as well. Any help would be appreaciated[image]

Edit: I know the process of how to get a reissue of a damaged passport but the website is vague and just wanted to ask people here if this will be counted as a damaged passport. As I was planning a travel trip abroad soon but the next passport appointment might take more time.

Comment: It's pretty minor damage, unlikely to raise suspicion of fraud, so you're not likely to have much trouble with it in most places, but some officers and some countries are more likely to take exception to it than others.  Better safe than sorry.

Comment: You seem to have created two accounts.  If you [merge](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them (or log in with the one you used to create this question), you will be able to edit the question and to post comments on it and its answers.

Comment: @Traveller that doesn't appear to be a duplicate; the question is _if_ the passport is damaged, not what to do if it is. i think we have some other questions along those lines but i'm having a bit of trouble finding the best ones.

Comment: @mlc The OP’s question is essentially asking for opinions. I suggested the duplicate because the answer contains a link to the official advice on the topic and the proposed duplicate is referenced here https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5099/canonical-question-on-indian-passport-damage as close to a canonical answer.

Comment: This should be fine. I had crossed borders with Indian passport with worse conditions than this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys.

Comment: I know it's not an exact duplicate but you are essentially asking for our opinion on the entity or the damage, which is not allowed at per our [help]. I prefer to close as duplicate rather than opinion based, because the former leaves more information available for future readers.

Comment: Ah sorry @JoErNanO didn't know about subjective questions, will keep that in mind from future.

Comment: @UtkarshMishra No worries.